# Два вопроса по ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Всем привет. Прошу прощения за глупые вопросы, но очень хочу разобраться. 
Есть код контроллера

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index(string One, string Two)
        {
            return View(new { One = One, Two = Two });
        }
    }
```

И код вьюхи

```
<div>
        @using(Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.TextBox("One")<br />
            @Html.TextBox("Two")<br />
            <input type="submit" value="Click" />
        }
        <br />
        @Html.Display("One")<br />
        @Html.Display("Two")<br />
    </div>
```

Модели нет вообще. Вьюха НЕтипизирована. Вопросы такие

1. Почему нет исключения при первом запуске метода действия, ведь он должен принимать два аргумента типа стринг, а они ему не передаются ?
2. Хочу понять по вьюхе, к чему привязываются хелперы, если модели нет в природе никакой ? И что за объект они передают методу Index, если модели нет ? Или вместо объекта модели они передают отдельные строки которые просто совпадают по имени с параметрами ?

Большое спасибо, че-то я завис на этом моменте

Новая версия контролла

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index(string One, string Two)
        {
            ViewBag.Prop = new MvcApplication6.Models.Class1 { One = One, Two = Two };
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Новая версия вью

```
<div>
        @using(Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.TextBox("One")<br />
            @Html.TextBox("Two")<br />
            <input type="submit" value="Click" />
        }
        <br />
        @if ((ViewBag.Prop.One != null) & (ViewBag.Prop.Two != null))
        {
        @ViewBag.Prop.One<br />
        @ViewBag.Prop.Two<br />
        }
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string` - reference type. Eсли аргументы не переданы - приходит `null`.

Тип свойства `Model` во вью по умолчанию - `dynamic`. Она просто выдает соответствующие свойства из реальной модели при совпадении имени.

Если `model == null` - хелперы просто считают значение пустым.

Строгая типизация нужна для строго типизированных хелперов, типа

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.SomeProperty)
```

А так же для защиты от случайной передачи модели не того типа. И, естественно, для нормальной допечатки в IDE.

Comment: Выходит если вьюхе передается Model = null , тогда не зависимо от того типизирована ли вьюха или нет, любые хелперы работают как с пустым значением ? Я попробовал создать типизированную вьюху и из контрола отправил View без аргументов и не смотря на то что использовал строготипизированные хелперы, то все равно все работало. Я правильно ли понял, что эти хелперы нужны лишь для того, чтобы при обратной отправке связать данные с моделью ? Спасибо.

Comment: Я еще один вопрос опубликовал, возможно вы знаете почему так http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423879/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F

Comment: @polyakov_s В вашем случае - да, хелперы нужны лишь для того, чтобы правильно сгенерировать текстбоксы с правильными ID, которые при отправке совпадут с именами полей модели.

Answer (score 1):

1. Исключения нет, т.к. string может быть нулем и поэтому параметры One,Two трактуются, как не обязательные. Сравните тоже самое с 'int', 'int?'
   https://dotnetfiddle.net/sRlNL2
   https://dotnetfiddle.net/OADSUx
2. Модель в вашем случае присутствует - это анонимный класс

   new { One = One, Two = Two }

сравните, если одно из полей будет с предустановленным значением
https://dotnetfiddle.net/KhtkTC
строчкой `@Html.Display("One")` вы говорите, что используя рефлексию вытащить значение поля One.
Вот типизированный объект передаем https://dotnetfiddle.net/GB7vPC
Как я понимаю директива @model во вьюхе нужна только для подсветки синтаксиса. Попробуйте в студии ввести название несуществующей модели. Подсветит как ошибку, но скомпилится.

Comment: Спасибо, по 1 вопросу все стало ясно. А по второму хочу немного уточнить. Я изменил контроллер, таким образом чтобы он во вью ничего не передавал. То есть просто View() и почему-то все равно строки TextBox отображаются нормально, ведь Model = null и рефлексия при запросе свойств с такими-то именами их не найдет. И по идее должен случиться эксепшн, но его нет. Почему ? Новую версию контроллера я выложил в своем вопросе вверху. Буду очень признателен вам.

Comment: Честно говоря насчет эксепшена не знаю, может они просто на null проверяют. Можно поискать в исходниках https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/

Comment: @polyakov_s, https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers/InputTagHelper.cs