# Почему не очищаются поля ввода если модель не передается

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Господа, подскажите пожалуйста почему при вводе данных в поля и отправке формы, данные введенные в поля остаются в полях ввода, ведь модель же не передается и следовательно поля ввода должны быть после отправки пустыми ?
Конторол

```
public ActionResult Index(string One, string Two)
        {
            ViewBag.Prop = new MvcApplication6.Models.Class1 { One = One, Two = Two };
            return View();
        }
```

Вью

```
<div>
        @using(Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.TextBox("One")<br />
            @Html.TextBox("Two")<br />
            <input type="submit" value="Click" />
        }
        <br />
        @if ((ViewBag.Prop.One != null) & (ViewBag.Prop.Two != null))
        {
        @ViewBag.Prop.One<br />
        @ViewBag.Prop.Two<br />
        }
    </div>
```

Очень благодарен буду !!

Comment: Может это сам браузер? FF очень любит так делать, попробуйте атрибут поля autocomplete="off"

Comment: Судя по всему, то дело не в браузере. Не могу че-то я понять, попоробовал в 5-ти разных браузерах

Comment: @polyakov_s - вы уже задавали похожий вопрос - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423341/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-asp-net-mvc/423347#423347. значения для полей ввода берутся из `ModelState`, а потом уже из модели. А в `ModelState` они не пустые. Даже если модель - null.

Comment: @polyakov_s могу явно дописать в тот ответ про то, как почистить поля.

Comment: Я честно говоря так и подумал, но все таки усомнился, так как я совсем еще новичок и боюсь делать поспешные выводы. Очень вам признателен

Comment: Если вас это не затруднит, то хотелось бы почитать

Comment: @polyakov_s дописал чуть-чуть

Comment: Спасибо большое. Теперь вроде как в голове упорядочилось все !